# SQL Select latest date from 3 tables

Tags: sql

I Have 3 tables, like this:
Table1

```
|   FID    | KID     |  NAME      |
| -------- | ------- | ---------- |
| 1001     | 1       | Tom        |
| 1002     | 2       | Jerry      |
| 1003     | 1       | Ronaldo    |
```

Table2

```
|    KID   |  KNAME     |
| -------- | ---------- |
| 1        | Mark       |
| 2        | Jessy      |
```

Table3

```
|    FID   |  KID    | DATE       |
| -------- | ------- | ---------- |
| 1001     | 1       | 10/01/2021 |
| 1002     | 2       | 15/01/2021 |
| 1003     | 1       | 10/01/2021 |
| 1001     | 1       | 15/03/2022 |
```

How i can select the max date and the results look like this:

```
|    FID   |  NAME     | KNAME      | DATE       |
| -------- | --------- | ---------- | ---------- |
| 1001     | Tom       | Mark       | 15/03/2022 |
| 1002     | Jerry     | Jessy      | 15/01/2021 |
| 1003     | Ronaldo   | Mark       | 10/01/2021 |
```

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and see [what is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply join and select Max Date. It's as simple as the below query:

```
SELECT 
     T3.FID, 
     T1.Name, 
     T2.KName, 
     MAX(T3.DATE) DATE
FROM TABLE3 T3
INNER JOIN TABLE1 T1 ON T1.FID = T3.FID
INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T2.KID = T3.KID
GROUP BY T3.FID, T1.Name, T2.KName
```